# Query working in SSMS but not in SSRS?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am using SQL Server 2012 Visual Studio 2010.

I've written the following query

```
SELECT  g.membercode, l.Value as AccountNum, ll.Value as Custodian, MAX(r.positiondate) as PositionDate
  FROM [APXFirm].[AdvApp].[vPortfolioGroupMemberFlattened] g
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [APXFirm].[AdvApp].[vPositionRecon] r
  ON g.MemberID = r.PortfolioID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [APXFirm].[AdvApp].[vPortfolioBaseCustomLabels] l
  on g.MemberID = l.PortfolioBaseID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [APXFirm].[AdvApp].[vPortfolioBaseCustomLabels] ll
  on g.MemberID = ll.PortfolioBaseID
  Where g.portfoliogroupcode = 'open'
  and PositionDate is NULL
  and l.label = '$numname'
  and ll.label = '$custdn'
  and ll.Value not in ('mbt', 'whittier')
  group by r.portfoliocode, g.membercode, l.Value, ll.Value
  order by ll.Value, g.MemberCode
```

In SQL Server Management Studio I get the following desired result set

```
membercode  AccountNum  Custodian   PositionDate
account1    123456      mssb       NULL
account2    78910       mssb       NULL
account3    11121314    mssb       NULL
account4    151617018   mssb       NULL
account5    19202122    mssb       NULL
```

However using the identical query in SSRS I am getting the following undesired result set where account name is showing up in the Custodian column and Member Code is 0

```
Member Code Account Number  Custodian   Position Date   Row Count
0           123456          account1                        1   
0           78910           account2                        2   
0           11121314        account3                        3   
0           151617018       account4                        4   
0           19202122        account5                        5
```

Any idea why this query works in SSMS but not SSRS?

Comment: Well - seeing as you select more columns and other aliases in the second query, they're not really identical, and it would be possible there might be an error in one or the other you've not spotted?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the `group by r.portfoliocode` is accomplishing. Or why you are obtaining `MAX(r.positiondate)` when you have constrained this to NULL in the WHERE clause. I would try a simplified query. Otherwise, I second Hansen.  The SSRS result set does not look like it came from the same query.

Comment: The point of the query is to cross reference two tables where a value from table g is not present in table r. In addition I want to know when the last date information was present. (Most often the result is a NULL value but not always.) The group by r.portfoliocode was not needed but even without it I still get the erroneous result set in SSRS.

Comment: If I remove table ll and all associates fields the query works in SSRS but I need the value in ll also which is from the same table as table l but I need to filter on a different field for that column.

Comment: Removing position date from the result set also makes it work in SSRS I would like to see this column though. I do need to filter on the value of it being NULL regardless of whether or not I display it.

Comment: Looking at the 2nd results set is that from a tablix on the report surface? The reason for the question is the header row text might not be the same as the field name, eg column header 'Custodian' looks like the source field it is returning 'membercode'.

Go to the 'Report Data' tab (Crtl+Alt+D) to open the window, expand the 'Datasets' node, then find the dataset that you placed the query into.  Right and mouse click on the data set name and select 'Dataset Properties'.  On the 'Query' panel find the 'Query designer..' button and run the query and see what result set looks like.

Comment: BobF That's a fair question but the actual field is the same as the header. So far removing r.Portfoliocode from group by and Position date from the selection set makes the report work. I had r.portfoliocode in the selection set previously but forgot to remove it from the group when I removed it from the selection set.I'm still curious if anyone in their experience has had a query work differently between SSMS and SSRS

Comment: Do you have datasets set up that provide data to the report?  If so when you look at the query in the dataset, then run the query for that dataset does it give you the same results you see in SSMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the reason why your results are different. But I would suggest creating a sproc and using that.

Also, you may as well remove PositionDate from the select as you have the clause `and PositionDate is NULL`